# к видиозаписи или к видеозаписям?

Tags: орфография

просит Вас предоставить доступ к видеозаписи за период с _____ по ________

Comment: Видио- или видео-?

Answer (score 1):

К видеозаписям - так лучше звучит и более логично.

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: А тут нужно зелёную галочку ставить (под цифрой со стрелками слева) - если ответ решил проблему.